# VARCHAR Column accepting N Prefixed string

Tags: sql, unicode, varchar, nvarchar

If I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE VarcharTest
(
    foo VARCHAR(12)
)
```

the column foo is data type varchar so should not accept unicode values. However, if I insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO VarcharTest VALUES ('abc') -- accepted
INSERT INTO VarcharTest VALUES ('я') -- not accepted
INSERT INTO VarcharTest VALUES (N'abc') -- accepted
INSERT INTO VarcharTest VALUES (N'я') -- not accepted
```

All the insert statements do as I would expect barring the third. The N prefix signifies this is a unicode string but we are inserting into a VARCHAR column which do not accept unicode.

Why does SQL server insert the value?

Comment: It's working as expected as far as I can see. Without N prefix, insert query does not recognize unicode string so it's inacceptable. Without nvarchar columns, the table will not know whether to store in ASCII or Unicode.

Comment: "Without N prefix, insert query does not recognize unicode string so it's inacceptable." but that's what the first statement is doing and it's accepted  - a non unicode value into a non unicode accepting datatype...

Comment: @SEarle1986 . . . SQL Server is able to translate the characters.  No surprise.  Similarly, `'123' + 0` works but `'123a' + 0` does not.

Comment: Thanks. Seems obvious bow you've said it!